# Ajax call return responseJSON.length undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to call below ajax to GetCustomerEntities. but i am getting   `result.length` & `responseJSON` undefined.Please let me know if i am missing something? jquery ver. : 1.10.2
Complete response is 200 , OK but on error, i am getting unexpected token 5, parseerror:

```
 var loadmyEntities = function (customerId, sucessCallBK) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http:/localhost:15343/Customer/GetCustomerEntities',
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { customerId: customerId},
success: function (result) {
                debugger
                if (result !== null && result.length !== 0) {
                    debugger
                            renderCustomerEntities(result, function () {
                                sucessCallBK(result);
                            });

                        }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
                    complete: function (result) {
                        debugger
                        if (result !== null && result.length !== 0) {
                            renderCustomerEntities(result, function () {
                                sucessCallBK(result);
                            });

                        }
                    }

                });

        };


var renderCustomerEntities = function (custEntity, callBk) {
    if (!(typeof custEntity.responseJSON == "string")) {
        var count = 0;
        if (custEntity.responseJSON === undefined) {
            count = custEntity.length;
        } else {
            count = custEntity.responseJSON.length;
        }
   }
}


public IEnumerable<CustomerResult> GetCustomerEntities(string customerId)
    {
        List<CustomerResult> parts = new List<CustomerResult>();

        // Add parts to the list.
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "crank arm", CustomerAddress = 1234 });
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "chain ring", CustomerAddress = 1334 });
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "regular seat", CustomerAddress = 1434 });
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "banana seat", CustomerAddress = 1444 });
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "cassette", CustomerAddress = 1534 });
        parts.Add(new CustomerResult() { CustomerName = "shift lever", CustomerAddress = 1634 });

        IEnumerable<CustomerResult> obj = parts;
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: `complete` fires regardless of what happens. if your server-side script doesn't send back anything, or sends back corrupted json, you'll STILL have `complete` fire. you need to check `success` and `error` as well. or at least see what the completion status is: `complete: function(obj, status) { console.log(status); }`

Comment: At your `debugger` statement, add: `console.dir(result)` - the result should already be an array of `CustomerResult` and as such won't have `responseJSON`.   jquery auto-converts from json before calling your complete function.  Also: Your `GetCustomerEntites` could return a `JsonResult`, but I've not tried it the way you have it so it might be ok.

Comment: @MarcB : it's returning 200

Comment: I agree with @MarcB - better to use separate `success` and `error` - would be clearer to see if you're getting an actual error

Comment: then put in a .error() handler as well. 200 just means the http layer worked, and says nothing about the CONTENT of the http response.

Comment: @MarcB 200 means apply `success` (unless I'm mistaken).  The MVC framework will return a 500 if there's an error in the server-side code.  Doesn't mean the mapping from Action->data worked though...

Comment: @MarcB : it's giving me SyntaxError: Unexpected token 5 Parsererror

Comment: there ya go. something's corrupted your json, or the service isn't outputting json in the first place.

Comment: @marcB : i have update my question for more clarity,can you please suggest on this.

Comment: `console.log` the jqhxr object. it'll contain the raw response text somewhere, then you can see what the server is spitting out.

Comment: @marcB : Here it is : Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.CustomerResult]", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: You have specified `dataType: 'json',` but your not returning json. `public JsonResult GetCustomerEntities(string customerId) { .... return Json(parts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not familiar with responseJson but if you want to return JSON you should just create a JSON result

```
public JsonResult GetCustomerEntities(string customerId)
{           
    return Json(__customerRepsitory.GetCustomerEntities(customerId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

on yeah.. and use success instead of complete

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http:/localhost:15343/Customer/GetCustomerEntities',
            async: true,
            data: { customerId: customerId},
            success: function (result) {
                debugger
                if (result !== null && result.length !== 0) {
                    renderCustomerEntities(result, function () {
                        sucessCallBK(result);
                    });

                }
            }

        });
```